# PHP - mysqli - check the table if a value is already inserted

Tags: php, mysql, post

I Am trying to check if the REF number added when creating a new `mysql` row is already in use. I don't have problems in adding a new row however, the script does not check the database first.

```
    if ($_POST['add_new_bus']){
    if (($_POST['add_ref'] != "")&&($_POST['add_name'] != "")&&($_POST['add_address'] != "")&&($_POST['add_area'] != "")){
        $add_ref = $_POST['add_ref'];
        $add_name = $_POST['add_name'];
        $add_address = $_POST['add_address'];
        $add_area = $_POST['add_area'];
        $chech_sql = "INSERT INTO `Details` (`REF`) VALUES ('$add_ref')";
   if (!($conn->query($chech_sql))) {
        echo "REF is already in use";
    }else{
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `Details` (`REF`, `NAME`, `ADDRESS`, `AREA`) VALUES ('$add_ref', '$add_name', '$add_address', '$add_area')");
        echo "<p style='float:right;'>" . $_POST['add_name'] . " " . "has been added to the register with REF number:" . " " . $_POST['add_ref'] . "</p>";
        }
    }
```

Any Idea how to check if the REF number is already in use?

Comment: First, run a SELECT query to find the row matching the REF number. Then run mysqli_num_rows($query) to see if there are more than 0 rows returned. If no rows are returned, you know there are no matching rows and you can proceed with the INSERT operation.

Comment: Is `REF` auto-incrementing? What is the goal, to update if the record already exists? Possibly useful, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Hi Chris, nope they are values already added . Olly I will try your suggestions

Comment: You could add a unique constraint on the table to disallow from insert the record more than once. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unique.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For giving you a correct idea how to do it, Please check below code:-

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['add_new_bus']){
    if (($_POST['add_ref'] != "") &&($_POST['add_name'] != "")&&($_POST['add_address'] != "")&&($_POST['add_area'] != "")){
        $add_ref = $_POST['add_ref'];
        $add_name = $_POST['add_name'];
        $add_address = $_POST['add_address'];
        $add_area = $_POST['add_area'];
        $chech_sql = "SELECT add_ref FROM Details WHERE add_ref = '".$add_ref."'";
        $result = $conn->query($chech_sql);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "REF is already in use";
    }else{
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `Details` (`REF`, `NAME`, `ADDRESS`, `AREA`) VALUES ('$add_ref', '$add_name', '$add_address', '$add_area')");
        echo "<p style='float:right;'>" . $_POST['add_name'] . " " . "has been added to the register with REF number:" . " " . $_POST['add_ref'] . "</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Note:- checking variables value and other things is up to you. because you only have them in your code.thanks.

Comment: @SNos  glad to help you :):)